# C# .Net application, some specific html pages not opening, renders empty screen on click

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using eLearningHub.Core.DataModel.Base;

namespace eLearningHub.Core.DataModel
{
    [Table("ClassEnroll")]
public class ClassEnroll : BaseModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Status { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("ClassModel")]
    [DisplayName("Class")]
    public int ClassId { get; set; }
    public ClassModel ClassModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TeacherModel")]
    [DisplayName("Teacher")]
    public int TeacherId { get; set; }
    public TeacherModel TeacherModel { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("StudentModel")]
    [DisplayName("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public StudentModel StudentModel { get; set; }

}
}
```

the above code is the C# core datamodel.

cshtml code:

```
@model IEnumerable<eLearningHub.Core.DataModel.ClassEnroll>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CourseListByStudent";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_DashBoard.cshtml";
}
<link href="~/Content/AdminLTE/Content/cardstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@if (TempData["Msg"] != null)
{
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-info"></i> info!</h4>
            @TempData["Msg"].ToString()
        </div>
    </div>

}
@if (TempData["FMsg"] != null)
{
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4><i class="icon fa fa-info"></i> Failed!</h4>
            @TempData["FMsg"].ToString()
        </div>
    </div>
}




@foreach (var c in Model)
{
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="box box-solid">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap width"></i>
                <h3 class="box-title">Class Details</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
                <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                    <dt>Class Name : </dt>
                    <dd>@c.ClassModel.ClassName</dd>
                   

                    <dt>Teacher : </dt>
                    <dd>@c.TeacherModel.Name</dd>
                    <dt> Email :</dt>
                    <dd> @c.TeacherModel.Email</dd>
                   

                    
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="@Url.Action("Class", "Classes", new {classRoom= c.ClassId})"><strong>Notes &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-sticky-note width"></i></strong></a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Class", "Classes", new {classRoom= c.ClassId})"><strong>Notice &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bullhorn width"></i></strong> </a> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a href="@Url.Action("ExamMark", "Student", new {id= c.ClassId})"><strong>Exam Mark&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-bullhorn width"></i></strong> </a>
                    
                </dl>
            </div>

            <!-- /.box-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.box -->
    </div>
}
```

Let me further explain my issue, I am running a .net application that i have done, however, I have many cshtml pages and all connected to an sql DB, everything in the program works perfectly except for some pages, they simply won't load whatsoever and I cant figure out why that is happening,
I have also realized that all the pages that are not working or even loading (no error given, simple an empty page)
All the pages that are not opening have the same public class ClassEnroll

any tips ?

Comment: Check the HTTP status code (in browser dev tools) returned by the empty page. My guess is 404

Comment: The data in the data is not displayed on your page. If the controller can get the data from the database. Did your controller return the correct page?